# Add new objet to the json data inside in map func

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

Hello folks I need to determine the top used three words inside of this string. And I want to do this with a JSON object. Actually, I tried before with the hashMap function but I can't update the values of the word.

How can I do that what is my fault?

```js
const text = "  //wont won't won't blue blue yellow won't ";
const wordList = text.split(' ').filter(String);

const obj = {}

wordList.map(word => (
  obj = { 
          ...obj, {
        word: word,
        count: +1
      }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be something like:

```
wordList.map(word => (
  if (! (word in obj)) {
    obj[word] = {
      word,  // not really necessary...?
      count: 0
    }
  }
  obj[word].count += 1;
)
```